# How to generate a mesh in an area with curves inside

Tags: finite-element-method, mesh

I would like to know how to generate a mesh inside an area, and be able to find the original curve outline inside the area from the mesh.

For example:
There is a rectangle inside which there is a curve with an implicit expression such as a segmented arc or a spline.

[image]

I mean let the red area generate a mesh and keep the shape of the inner curve.

What is the solution?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want the mesh elements to follow a curve, or does the curve have a 'thickness' that you want to remove or mesh separately?

Comment: @user21 In fact, what I want is a curve without thickness

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
pts = {{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, -1}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}};
f = BSplineFunction[pts]; bm1 = 
 ToBoundaryMesh[DiscretizeGraphics[ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 1}]]];
bm2 = ToBoundaryMesh[Rectangle[{0, -1/2}, {6, 2}]];
(* ResourceFunction["FEMAddOnsInstall"][] *)
Needs["FEMAddOns`"]
bm = BoundaryElementMeshJoin[bm1, bm2];
ToElementMesh[bm]["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

Another approach can be seen in the documentation [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToElementMesh.html#1088111747):

[image]

Stealing from @kgl's answer:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hp0Z3.png"];
bmr = ImageMesh@img;
ToElementMesh[bmr]["Wireframe"]
ToElementMesh[bmr, "RegionHoles" -> None]["Wireframe"]
```

The point I am trying to make is that you can decide if the inner region is to be excluded or not; in other words if it's a material region of an outside or just a curve the mesh should follow, because you need measurements along that curve.

[image]

Comment: The first answer is very good, but the fly in the ointment is that the mesh around the curve is too dense, the second answer looks a lot more reasonable, but this causes the limit of the generated mesh to become a closed area (whether hollow or non-hollow)

Comment: @OIW, unfortunately, I do not understand your comment. Can you reword this?

Comment: What I mean is that this curve has no thickness, it doesn't look thick in the picture (ie wireless thin)

Answer (score 5):

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hp0Z3.png"];


ImageMesh @ img
```

[image]

```
DiscretizeRegion @ ImageMesh @ img
```

[image]

```
ImageMesh @ DeleteBorderComponents[ColorNegate @ Binarize @ img]
```

[image]

```
DiscretizeRegion[
 ImageMesh @ DeleteBorderComponents[ColorNegate @ Binarize @ img], 
 MaxCellMeasure -> {"Area" -> 10}]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[1];
f = BSplineFunction[RandomReal[1, {15, 2}], SplineClosed -> True];
pp = ParametricPlot[f[u], {u, 0, 1}, Frame -> True, 
  FrameTicks -> False, ImagePadding -> 0, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, AbsoluteThickness[3]], 
  FrameStyle -> AbsoluteThickness[10], Background -> Red]
```

[image]

```
ImageMesh @ Image @ pp
```

[image]

```
DiscretizeRegion @ ImageMesh @ Image @ pp
```

[image]

Comment: This looks great, but I want the curve to have no thickness, which means a non-closed curve (the pic I uploaded the curve has thickness lol)

Answer (score 0):

Something like e.g.:

```
pts = {{1, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, -1}, {4, 1}, {5, 0}};
f = BSplineFunction[pts]; Show[
 ParametricPlot[f[t], {t, 0, 1}, PlotTheme -> "Business"], 
 Graphics[{Red, Opacity[0.1], Rectangle[{0, -.2}, {5.5, 2}]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I have some problems with my instructions, the mesh refers to triangular elements such as the mesh generated by the method ToElementMesh.